# repeating variable declaration in different function

Tags: javascript, dom

Can someone clarify for me please, regarding the following code, am attempting some of "the odin project" projects. so please take a look a my code and tell me if its a good idea to have diff functions with the DOM variable declaration.

here's my code:

```
function drawGrid(){
 const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

 for(let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        this.classList.add("changeColor");
    });
 }
}

function reset(){
 const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

 for(let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){

    resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        squares[i].classList.remove("changeColor");
    });
 }
}
```

as you can see i used .square class, and am wondering if there is any other way to make the code a little more shorter.
Thanks

Comment: Are both of these functions in the same file?

Comment: If you want to avoid querying the squares twice (why?), you can make your functions accept an argument and pass the DOM element as an argument to them. In general, don't optimize until you really understand what is you want to gain.